# Java how do I make this code shorter?

Tags: java

so I am working on my program which sorts random numbers by using sorting techniques, such as quick sorting and bubble sorting.
I wrote codes, and I realized that my codes are repeating but I do not know how to shorten them because they are very similar but some of the signs are different... 
For example,

```
if (radioButAscending.isSelected()){    //ascending order
            for(int i=0;i<numbers.size()-1;i++){
                int minNum=i;   

                for (int j=i+1;j<numbers.size();j++){
                    if(numbers.get(j)<numbers.get(minNum)){
                        tempNum=numbers.get(i);
                        numbers.set(i,numbers.get(j) ); //change numbers[i] to numbers[j] (numbers.get(i) = numbers.get(j))  
                        numbers.set(j,tempNum); //numbers.get(j)=tempNum
                    }
                }
            }
            showSortedNumbers();
        } else {    //descending order
            for(int i=0;i<numbers.size()-1;i++){
                int minNum=i;   
                for (int j=i+1;j<numbers.size();j++){
                    if(numbers.get(j)>numbers.get(minNum)){
                        tempNum=numbers.get(i);
                        numbers.set(i,numbers.get(j) ); //change numbers[i] to numbers[j] (numbers.get(i) = numbers.get(j))  
                        numbers.set(j,tempNum); //numbers.get(j)=tempNum
                    }
                }
            }
            showSortedNumbers(); 
        }
```

those are my codes, and as you can see the codes are very similar except these codes;
`if(numbers.get(j)<numbers.get(minNum)){
if(numbers.get(j)>numbers.get(minNum)){`

so my question is.. how do I make this shorter? I tried to make a subroutine, but the sign was different so I could not make it.. Please help guys Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: sort one way or the other, and use some form of reverse()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll take into account that you want to use your custom approach, and only deduplicate.  If you want to use `Collections`, that'd reduce your code to four lines tops.

First, the only difference between those two code blocks is the innermost `if` statement; one compares `<` and the other compares  `>`.  Everything else they do is the same.

This particular code isolates the conditional behavior and reduces the repetition of the whole loop statements.

```
boolean ascendingOrder = radioButAscending.isSelected();
for (int i = 0; i < numbers.size() - 1; i++) {
    int minNum = i;

    for (int j = i + 1; j < numbers.size(); j++) {
        if (ascendingOrder) {
            if (numbers.get(j) < numbers.get(minNum)) {
                tempNum = numbers.get(i);
                numbers.set(i, numbers.get(j)); //change numbers[i] to numbers[j] (numbers.get(i) = numbers.get(j))
                numbers.set(j, tempNum); //numbers.get(j)=tempNum
            }
        } else {
            if (numbers.get(j) > numbers.get(minNum)) {
                tempNum = numbers.get(i);
                numbers.set(i, numbers.get(j)); //change numbers[i] to numbers[j] (numbers.get(i) = numbers.get(j))
                numbers.set(j, tempNum); //numbers.get(j)=tempNum
            }
        }
    }
}
showSortedNumbers();
```

Can we do better?  **Absolutely!**

We define a new method `compare`, which takes two arguments from the collection, and does a compare operation for us.  It basically takes the responsibility of the boolean logic in this method.

```
private <T extends Comparable<T>> boolean compare(T left, T right, boolean isAscending) {
    return isAscending ?
            left.compareTo(right) <= 0 :
            right.compareTo(left) <= 0;
}
```

If we're ascending, then we compare the left value to the right value to see if it's less (4 and 17; 4 is less than 17).  If we're descending, we compare the opposite way (4 and 17; 17 is greater than 4).

That reduces the code block to this:

```
boolean ascendingOrder = radioButAscending.isSelected();
for (int i = 0; i < numbers.size() - 1; i++) {
    int minNum = i;

    for (int j = i + 1; j < numbers.size(); j++) {
        if (compare(numbers.get(j), numbers.get(minNum), ascendingOrder)) {
            tempNum = numbers.get(i);
            numbers.set(i, numbers.get(j)); //change numbers[i] to numbers[j] (numbers.get(i) = numbers.get(j))
            numbers.set(j, tempNum); //numbers.get(j)=tempNum
        }
    }
}
showSortedNumbers();
```

Comment: thank you so much! works perfectly fine and very easy to understand! God bless you :)

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( ascending )
    Collections.sort( numbers );
else
    Collections.sort( numbers, Collections.reverseOrder() );
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Java 8:

```
Collections.sort(numbers,
    radioButAscending.isSelected() ?
        Comparator.naturalOrder() : Comparator.reverseOrder());
showSortedNumbers();
```